# node install cordova / ionic / Foundation/Foundation.h not found

Tags: ios, node.js, macos, cordova

im trying to install cordova on a osx mavericks mac and get this error:

npm install -g cordova ionic

$ ionic start myApp tabs

$ cd myApp

$ ionic platform add ios

$ ionic build ios

```
..../platforms/ios/CordovaLib/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch:21:13: fatal error: 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        ^
```

1 error generated.

- XCode Command Line tools are up to date.
- npm is up to date.
- xcode version: Version 5.1.1 (5B1008)

cordova without ionic get the same error.
phonegap itself thet the same error.

any idea whats wrong?

thx

Comment: Not sure it's relevant here, but after you install Xcode you need to run it once to accept the EULA before many of the command line tools will work. I don't think that should prevent linking to a library, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: any update if you got this resolved? i'm running on the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been looking for answer to this for a couple of days and all I needed to do is to uninstall XCode (installed via AppStore). Then re-install it (will take some time coz the new XCode is 2.18GB!).

NOTE: Keep your current cordova, node, npm and ionic installs.